# DAX and PowerQuery Calculate issue

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables. TableA and TableB. In TableB I have a field called 'Status' that contains values "complete", "In Progress"

I want to create the following field in TableA based on the following calculation from DAX,  using PowerQuery

CALCULATE(COUNT('Table B'[Status],'Table B'[Status]="Complete")/COUNTROWS('Table B')

The following line is what I put in PowerQuery, but it is not giving me the correct out put.

Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Table B",each [Status] = "Complete"))/Table.RowCount(#"Table B")

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you are expecting and the incorrect output which the PowerQuery statement is giving you?

Comment: Do you have a relationship between the two tables in the data model? If so you will need to factor that in, in your PowerQuery, otherwise you will get the same value for all rows.

Comment: @SamNseir  Yes, I have a relationship between the two tables in the data model. How do I factor that in PowerQuery

Comment: What are the columns of A and B with the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship between the two tables, then you'll need to factor that in. The following assumes `Table A` has a column `CatA` that is joined to `Table B` on column `CatB`.

Custom Column formula:

```
let
  relatedRows = Table.SelectRows(#"Table B", (b) => b[CatB] = [CatA]),
  completed = Table.SelectRows(relatedRows,each [Status] = "Complete"),
  out = Table.RowCount(completed) / Table.RowCount(relatedRows)
in
  out
```

Full example query for context:

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Completed", each 
    let
      relatedRows = Table.SelectRows(#"Table B", (b) => b[CatB] = [CatA]),
      completed = Table.SelectRows(relatedRows,each [Status] = "Complete"),
      out = Table.RowCount(completed) / Table.RowCount(relatedRows)
    in
      out
  , Percentage.Type)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```